# WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 Sample 271 Failed to locate XSD resource

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 and trying to implement Sample 271: File Processing.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+271%3A+File+Processing

I have followed every step as mentioned in the sample guide. When trying to execute, it gives error:

```
    [2015-10-06 10:41:09,024]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:247f4674-cd22-461e-88c2-6f12693a7d67, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = XML error occurred while creating the Smooks configuration from the config key: smooks Caused by Failed to locate XSD resource '/META-INF/ns/synapse' on classpath. Namespace: 'http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse'., Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">
    Don, Smith, 123456789
    &#xd;
    John, Smith, 987654321
    </text></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
    [2015-10-06 10:41:09,025] DEBUG - LogMediator End : Log mediator
    [2015-10-06 10:41:09,026] DEBUG - DropMediator Start : Drop mediator
    [2015-10-06 10:41:09,026] DEBUG - DropMediator End : Drop mediator
    [2015-10-06 10:41:09,027] DEBUG - SequenceMediator End : Sequence         <fault>
    [2015-10-06 10:41:12,308] ERROR - MailTransportSender Error creating         mail message or sending it to the configured server
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMail(MailTransportSender.java:494)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMessage(MailTransportSender.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    [2015-10-06 10:41:12,312] ERROR - MailTransportSender Error generating mail message
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error creating mail message or sending it to the configured server
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.handleException(AbstractTransportSender.java:226)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMail(MailTransportSender.java:505)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMessage(MailTransportSender.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMail(MailTransportSender.java:494)
    ... 6 more
    [2015-10-06 10:41:12,318]  INFO - AxisEngine [MessageContext: logID=b5929ba2da80889c3ab62f36ecb6135d5b61e29a42314ca3] Error generating mail message
    [2015-10-06 10:41:12,318] ERROR - AsyncCallback Error generating mail message
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error generating mail message
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.handleException(AbstractTransportSender.java:226)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender.sendMessage(MailTransportSender.java:184)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
```

Files required for sample are available here:

https://docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/38472395/sample_vfs.zip?version=1&modificationDate=1401834663000&api=v2

Am I doing anything wrong here or this XSD file is removed from mentioned location?

Any help or tip on this is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please post you local entry, it is likely you have a xmlns conflict

Comment: Thanks Jason for pointing towards correct direction, although I have already resolved this issue but forgot to mentioned here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating local entry using WSO2 UI, it adds an extra entry automatically for http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse.
Removing this manually from local entry file (xml file on the file system) resolved the issue.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried removing the extra entry  http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse but nothing changes. Infact it is added again.